# How many alkanes having a molecular weight of hundred, are chiral?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, chirality

I successfully found 2, but the answer key says that there are 4 such compounds possible. I found:

- 3-methyl hexane
- 2,3-dimethyl pentane

We can't have a cyclic ring as the masses won't match. What else could be made folks?

Comment: Are rings allowed?

Comment: Yeah, I just forgot about the rings!!

Comment: Yeah but then if you make a ring the molecular weight won't match

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are essentially correct.  Of the [nine isomers of heptane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptane#Isomers_and_enantiomers), only two are chiral.  However, if you count each enantiomer as a separate molecule, then there are "four" chiral isomers:

1. (R)-3-methylhexane
2. (S)-3-methylhexane
3. (R)-2,3-dimethylpentane
4. (S)-2,3-dimethylpentane

Comment: What about a cyclobutyne ring with the triple bond between C1 and C2, and then one H and one ethynyl group -CCH on the third Carbon atom, and a group =C=CH2 on the 4th Carbon atom ? I am not sure this structure does make sense, with such a bent triple bond C-C. But it is C8H4 with molecular weight 100, and it is chiral.

Comment: Good find.  But, the question specifies alkanes.

Comment: Also Maurice I think cyclooctyne is the first cyclic alkyne that is reasonably stable.  Has anyone every reported a structure anywhere close to a 4-membered annular alkyne?  If not, you could write down infinity more structures that are chiral (e.g. C7H30, C2H100, C8H2, etc. etc.) and argue that maybe they are stable somehow at 100 K and a few terapascals of pressure....who knows after all?